# Which pronoun to replace an infinitive?

Tags: pronoms, infinitif

I have a pair of question and answer:

> Pourquoi est-ce que tu veux voyager ?
>
> Je veux voyager pour visiter de nouveaux pays.

I want to replace `voyager` in the answer by a pronoun, and I thought that

> Je le veux pour visiter de nouveaux pays

would work, but my teacher said that it was wrong.

When I asked him which pronoun I should use instead, I was told that there's no suitable pronouns to replace the infinitive in this case, and that I should reuse the infinitive (`voyager`) in my answer.

However, there can certainly be cases where repeating the infinitive would be awkward, such as when it's long. In those cases, what pronouns (or perhaps other structures) can I use to replace the infinitive? Thank you.

Comment: Just wondering, what's the English translation? My guess: *"Why do you want to travel?"* With infinitive: *"I want to travel to visit new countries."* Pronomial: *"I want it to visit new countries."* (This is also not idiomatic in English, btw.) Dimitris's answer: *"To visit new countries."* Luke's answer: *"I want to do it ..."*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

« Je le veux » is actually okay to my ears, though not idiomatic according to the native speakers who have weighed in. Arguably this *le* wouldn't replace the infinitive but whatever substantive is implied by the infinitive (e.g. « un voyage »).

---

A more common solution is to replace the verb by another. The general one is **(le) faire** :

> Pourquoi veux-tu voyager ?
>
> Je veux le faire parce que je veux visiter de nouveaux pays.

It might seem like « le faire » hardly saves time and effort over repeating « voyager », but two points may be made: that this isn't essential for pronouns, as long as they help you avoid repetition; and that the mileage will vary depending on the length of the original phrase, since it can replace everything branched under the verb:

> Si, elle t'a dit qu'elle ne consentira plus de te voir autant qu'elle vivra, mais elle **l'a fait** dans le seul but de te rendre jaloux.
>
> <sub>*You could also say **l'a dit** here, repeating the verb but not the rest.*</sub>

Also see Gilles' comment about possibly using a different verb depending on the situation. For example, if you want to *voyager* to a specific place, you might replace that verb phrase by *y aller* instead of *le faire*. This makes sense to me. I wonder if there might be a few atomic verbs that "catch" different categories, like *faire*, *aller*, *être*, *avoir* (these last two certainly can't be replaced by *le faire*).

---

Finally, Dimitris' suggestion is certainly applicable to everyday conversations if you just meant that you were looking for a practical way to avoid repeating a verb.

Comment: Nice answer Luke! +1

Comment: Thanks you. Would you say `le faire` is used often in spoken French? In English, saying `I like it` to avoid saying, for example, `I like to ride my bike` would be very common I think.

Comment: Actually, while “je veux le faire” is less unidiomatic than “je le veux”, it's not really idiomatic either. I'm not sure why. I think “le faire” is for a specific action rather than for a general habit, but it's not just that. It sounds a bit strange even in “Pourquoi veux-tu aller en Thailande cet été ? — Je veux _y aller_ parce que …” (not “le faire”). It is indeed strange, because your example where “le faire” stands for “dire …” is perfectly idiomatic. Cc @seismatica

Comment: In this case, "Je veux le faire" sounds a lot more natural than "je le veux", IMHO.

Comment: @seismatica  Thanks you is wrong. It should have been either thanks or thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry if I didn't get your query. What is wrong with the following reply?

> Pourquoi est-ce que tu veux voyager ?
>
> (Juste) pour visiter de nouveaux pays.

You avoid repeating voyager.

There is indeed the so-called pronom neutre **le**. This is used to replace among other things infinitive verbs. (See for instance: http://uoh.concordia.ca/pronoms/co/m/co/Le_pronom_neutre_le_-_B1.html)

> Avez-vous prévu de sortir ? Oui, je l'ai prévu.
>
> Voudriez-vous voyager ? Oui, je le voudrais.

In any case your reply doesn't sound peculiar to me (albeit not a native speaker). Your usage of *le* (as a neutral pronoun) does not contradict any grammar rules I am familiar with but may be is not so idiomatic (to be verified by native speakers).

E.g., in the same spirit one can say (see here http://www.aidenet.eu/grammaire12.htm)

> Il pleut, je le savais.

See also Luke's excellent answer (much more experienced and properly educated than me:-)!).

Comment: Merci, though I think this is one where a native speaker might correct me on the "je le veux" option.. we'll see! Meanwhile, +1.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Thanks also! By the way since you are a writer and translator (among other interesting things:-)!) I would like to hear your opinion in my recent Monty Python related questions if you have time of course.

Comment: I confirm that starting the reply with “pour” is the most idiomatic way. (Or “juste pour” or “simplement pour” — “juste” is maybe a bit of an anglicism there, but it's a widely accepted one.)

Answer (score 5):

*Je le veux* is not technically wrong but is not idiomatic in this context.

It is somewhat too formal and too strong, and only used in occasions where it implies a strong commitment, often religious, especially a wedding (Yes, I will / Yes, I want to), or a "[divorce](https://www.archambault.ca/livres/oui-je-le-veux-vive-le-qu%C3%A9bec-libre-vol1-no2-dossier-multiculturalisme/ouellet-martine-al/9782924999035/?id=2880719&cat=)"?

Both suggestion in Luke's and Dimitris' answers (*Pour visiter de nouveaux pays* and *je veux le faire pour...*) are idiomatic so better than *je le veux pour...*.

Answer (score 1):

This is found in the literature, but there aren't too many cases;

- ... faisaient ricaner ou me dégoûtaient parce que je les trouvais hypocrites, ennuyeuses, enfin vous voyez ce que je veux dire.
  — Je vois, oui. Et maintenant, vous voulez faire partie de ces gens biens, c'est ça ?
  — Je le veux. Je le veux pour mon fils.(*Le miroir noir*, Anna Galore - 2010)
- Je renonce à tout ce qui n'est pas vous ; je veux pratiquer la pauvreté comme vous me le demandez par ma Sainte Règle; je le veux, parce que je vous l'ai promis par un engagement sacré; je le veux pour ne pas provoquer vos châtiments ...(*Le rédemptoriste imitant Jésus-Christ par la pratique des douze ...*, Arthur-J. Mouton - 1909)

However, your teacher seems to be right, in current French you'd repeat the verb or say rather something like this;

> Pourquoi est-ce que tu veux voyager ?
>   C'est ce que je veux parce que *j'ai envie de/je veux* visiter de nouveaux pays.